# Parameterizing adhoc scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

In SQL server I always had a set of diagnostic scripts and always made sure to declare variables with identifiers so that my other selects and updates would leverage them. I'm having trouble adopting this pattern in Oracle.

I might have 4 or 5 select queries, and then also some updates that I may uncomment once I've verified the results.  I want to see the results of the select queries in output.

I am using SQL Developer.

First I tried using a `DEFINE` block, but it seems this must be paired with BEGIN/END block, and once a query is inside a block, it seems like it becomes cumbersome to view the results.  The examples I've seen either involve setting a cursor then iterating over the cursor to print results, or you must print individual values which is even more cumbersome.

So instead I tried using variable's since I can reference them without declare/begin/end, but I am having trouble setting the value of the variable:

```
variable customerid number;
customerid := 1234;
```

But I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 5 in command - customerid := 1234 Error
>   report - Unknown Command

I also tried

```
select t.customerid into :customerid
from customer t
where t.customerid = 1234
```

and get:

> SQL Error: ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
>   01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"

**My goal is to have my id declarations at the top where I set the values, and be able to run the script and all my adhoc selects appear in output.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the bind variable in a PL/SQL context, either with an [`execute` syntactic wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm):

```
variable customerid number;
exec :customerid := 1234;
```

or slightly more explicitly:

```
variable customerid number;
begin
  :customerid := 1234;
end;
/
```

which is (almost) equivalent, but will probably be more convenient if you want to set multiple variables. You can populate the bind variabke from a query too, as you attempted, but that also needs to be in a PL/SQL context:

```
begin
  select t.customerid into :customerid
  from customer t
  where t.customerid = 1234;
end;
/
```

Notice the colon before `customerid`, indicating it is a bind variable, in all of those. You need that when you reference it later, e.g. in a SQL query (which doesn't need to be in a PL/SQL block):

```
 select * from customer where customerid = :customerid;
```

You can use the same mechanism in your updates later. The exception to using a colon is if you want to just see the value of the variable; you could `select :customerid from dual`, but [there is also the ability to](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm)

```
print customerid
```

That's even more useful if your variable is a `refcursor`.

---

`define` is a completely different mechanism, for [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) rather than bind variables. You don't need to use PL/SQL blocks for this either:

```
define customerid=1234
select * from customer where customerid = &customerid;
```

Notice there is no colon this time. And also note that if your variable is a string, you need to enclose it in quotes when you use it:

```
define name=aaron
select * from users where first_name = '&name';
```

You can also use the result of a query to populate a substitution variable, using [the `new_value` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref799).

Comment: Thanks Alex for clearing up the syntax  and terminology. That trailing `/` after `end;` made a big difference in being able to follow a begin/end block with other selects. What is that called?

Comment: @AaronLS - [a slash](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm) *8-)  See also [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663). (Those are all links to the SQL\*Plus documentation, but - by design - most of it applies to SQL Developer, which is less well documented generally...)